# Aligning images about right bottom corner

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am using relative layout to superimpose one smaller image on top of a larger one.
I want the bottom-right corner of the smaller image to coincide with B-R corner of the larger image. I'm using margin parameters in my layout XML (specifying measurement in dips) but this doesn't seem to work for all devices and resolutions - in some cases the small image is shifted by 4-5px from the border.

Is it possible to specify the position of the smaller image without pixel values? I.e. with gravity or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/big_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/bigimage"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/little_image"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/big_image"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/big_image"
        android:src="@drawable/littleimage"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Nice thing about `RelativeLayout` is that you can use *relative* positions and dimensions, instead of using specific dips or pixels. In the case above, I just played with the `android:layout_align*` parameters, to make sure that both images are aligned. Keep in mind that I set a specific dimension of the little image, but you can change that to fit your needs.

Comment: great! just what i was looking for