# XML Absolute Layout put image in Bottom Left and Bottom Right

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, view

Hello I want to make one application in which i am using Absolute layout and in that layout i am using two images i want to put one image in bottom left and another in bottom right can you help me how can i do this with xml or with java

My code is

```
  <AbsoluteLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="10dp" android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout">
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/hk1" />
  <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgDel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/kitty"
         android:layout_gravity="left"
         />
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/delete"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
         />

 </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: But i have created so many thing based on absolute layout if i change layout i have to change so many things in java also

Comment: No user370305 it is displaying if i put manually x,y value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use some thing like this

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/big_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/bigimage"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/little_image"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/big_image"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/big_image"
        android:src="@drawable/littleimage"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

refered from [relative layout aligning images about right bottom corner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079410/relative-layout-aligning-images-about-right-bottom-corner)